# jQuery keypress to work normally except hitting enter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to trigger a `click` if enter is pressed inside an `input` tag, but would like to have the default event strategy in all other cases. I have tried it this way:

```
$("#keywords").keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.charCode === 13) {
        $("#campus-search").click();
    } else {
        $("#keywords").val($("#keywords").val() + String.fromCharCode(e.charCode));
    }
});
```

It works, but I am still not satisfied, because when I click inside the `input` somewhere in the middle of text or press the left button, or home button and then try to type some text, it will show it at the end of the input, which is bad user-experience. Can I keep the `input` to work in the default way except the case when enter is pressed?

Comment: Questions is unclear...the behaviour that i think you want is already the default behaviour

Comment: Yes question doesn't explain it...What is being clicked..a button. Why? Not just use form submit functionality.. When i press left or  home button and type text doens't go at end.

Comment: It might depend on your browser.

Comment: Which browser do you have?

Comment: I am working for all browsers, but I am firmly convinced that you do not understand the question. Let me try to explain. You have the text "foo" inside the input. You click after "fo" and before the last "o". You type "bar" there and you should have the text of "fobaro". Instead you will have the text of "foobar". This is the normal behavior for my code, which by the way does not differ from your code, except the part where you prevent all default events.

Comment: can you post jsfiddle...Because i do get *fobaro*..and i haven't posted any code.. i understand the question but i am not sure if problem really does exists as nothing similar to what you have been describing is happening.

Comment: Muhammad, thanks for trying to help, but please, take a look at the answer of codezombie. He really has a nice solution there which was fully enough to solve the problem.

Comment: You are welcome. It appears everything was working normally...user can click anywhere and it will type there and whenever he presses enter, click for button is triggered. I can only guess that part `$("#keywords").val($("#keywords").val() + String.fromCharCode(e.charCode));` was unnecessary and was the culprit.

Comment: No, the problem was that I have tried with keypress instead of keyup and have hacked the event to be as normal as possible, but it was not enough, because the problem I have described in the question. codezombie's solution did exactly what I have wanted to initially, but he did not commit my mistake of working with the keypress event and correctly used the keyup event, which was the key to the solution. Also, charCode is deprecated, according to his answer and we should use keyCode in keyup. Man, that's a fantastic answer, fully deserves all the upvotes.

Comment: Take a look: His answer Plus the bad (link at end). Code above equals the bad behavior of **foobar** instead of **fobaro**. The code above takes all the text in textbox whenever key is pressed then adds the char code at **END** and then put that modified text back into the textbox. You could just use div here... http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/5XXED/

Comment: Muhammad, the problem was solved, all tests were successful. I will not accept your answer, as it was not solving the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#test").keyup(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            $("#campus-search").click();
        }
    });

    $("#campus-search").click(function () {
        console.log("BUTTON IS CLICKED");
    });
});
```

The `input` will act completely **normal** and everything works on `default`, **unless** when you press the enter button (*keyCode = 13*), then the button `.click()` event will be triggered.

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Mz2g8/3/

————

# **Update**: Just one hint for the code in your question, do *not* use `charCode`, as it is **deprecated**.

> This feature has been removed from the Web. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. Do not use it in old or new projects. Pages or Web apps using it may break at any time.

*(E.g. `charCode` does not work with FF v29.0.1)*

And something different but *important* to know:

> charCode is **never** set in the **keydown** and **keyup** events. In these cases, keyCode is set instead.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.charCode

Comment: Interesting, first tests are successful. I am up-voting your answer anyway, but if your post survives the full tests I will accept it as an answer. Thanks, man!

Comment: Let me know when something isn't working as you expect it, then I'll have a look and try to improve the code. Glad I could help :-)

Comment: Very nice answer, friend, great job.

Answer (score 0):

The [`keypress`](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) function does not capture non-printing keys, such as <kbd>shift</kbd>, <kbd>esc</kbd>, <kbd>delete</kbd>, and <kbd>enter</kbd>, so the best way to go about this would be have two event handlers: one for `keypress`, as you have defined above, and one for `keydown` that checks for the `charCode` 13 and then performs the `click()` event on `$(#campus-search)` if that keycode is passed (by an <kbd>enter</kbd> press).

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/7Jah3/)**

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$("#keywords").keypress(function(e) {
if (e.charCode === 13) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent default action of the event if the event is keypress of enter key
    $("#campus-search").click();
} else {
    $("#keywords").val($("#keywords").val() + String.fromCharCode(e.charCode));
}
});
```

Comment: Let me clarify the problem: The solution writes the characters at the end of the content, regardless of your position. Try your event on an input. Click inside the input, press the home button and type something. You would expect your characters to appear at the start of the text after pressing home, but it appears at the end of the string. So your solution is not an improvement.

Comment: Can you make jsfiddle what you are saying isn't happening. If i click input then press home and type it does type at start..?

Comment: This is a user event. When you expect to type somewhere not at the end of the text, it will still type at the end of the text. What else would you like the line of $("#keywords").val($("#keywords").val() + String.fromCharCode(e.charCode)); to do? It is pretty simple:

Comment: If we have a text of "read the question" and we want to type "pay attention when" at the start of the string, so the result would be "pay attention when you read the question", this will not happen, the text you want to type at the start of the text box will be typed at the end of the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can eliminate the `else` clause entirely to get your desired result.

Look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/du36a/).

Comment: I did. Confirmed at least for version 29 on Mac OS X 10.9.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:

**HTML:**

```
<input id="keywords" type="text" value="" />
<input id="campus-search" type="button" value="Campus Search" />
```

**JavaScript / jQuery:**

```
$("#keywords").keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.charCode === 13) {
        $("#campus-search").click();
    } else {
        $("#keywords").val($("#keywords").val() + String.fromCharCode(e.charCode));
    }
});

$("#campus-search").on("click", function () {
    alert("Searching..");
});
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ynevet/vQDd9/)

Comment: Under Chrome if I remove the else part it is not modifying the value of the input

Comment: @LajosArpad You want to modify the input?

Comment: Yes, I want to be able to type something inside the input and when I hit enter I would like to trigger a click.

Comment: My goal is to achieve default event handling except the case when enter is pressed.

Comment: @LajosArpad default event handling of which event?

Comment: Of all events. I would like the input to work exactly as other inputs, with the only exception, that enter triggers a click.

Comment: @LajosArpad I'm sorry, but I can't understand what you want and why my code is not good enough for you.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, but please, take a look at the accepted answer. It really solves the problem and lets you to use the default events of the tag.

Comment: I think there is some misunderstanding about events...all events are default we are merely detecting them.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer, we know what events are, but when we create an event handler, we modify the behavior of the affected structural elements. As the question stated, I want the affected structural elements to behave exactly as default with the only difference being that when the user hits enter, a click should be triggered. Your suggestion of submitting forms was not helpful, as form submitting is not the same as clicking.

Comment: we don't magically modify behavior of any **affected structural elements**. Unless you explicitly want to. Just specifying a listener doesn't affect any element. Textbox wasn't working as normally because of the weird code above which was overwriting the value of textbox and not because there was a event handler attached to it. And if you are triggering click on submit button then it's the same, but if it's being loaded using ajax then it's not.